# RadioButton: How to change the IsChecked state?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

If a RadioButton is in the InChecked state, then the button has a black toggle. How can I change that so that is is white instead of black?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will probably have to re-template your radiobutton control either by editing the default template found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296247%28VS.95%29.aspx), or by using Blend (if you have it available).  Blend will likely be a lot easier if you're familiar with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            radioButton1.IsChecked = false;
        }
    }
}
```